# Trouble with gem installations

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, nokogiri

I am in a coding bootcamp and I have encountered an error in which I am having a hard time fixing. I currently in an exercise where I am learning how to create dynamic routes. Every time I run my server I am getting errors when I go to my routes and it states that:

```
Could not find nokogiri-1.8.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I tried to `bundle install` after adding `nokogiri` to my gemfile but all I get is this error below. I need some help cause I don't know what is going on and I am a total noob in regards to this stuff.

```
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.5
Ignoring websocket-driver-0.7.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine websocket-driver --version 0.7.0
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........
Using rake 12.3.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 0.9.5
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using activesupport 5.1.5
Using activemodel 5.1.5
Using arel 8.0.0
Using activerecord 5.1.5
Using public_suffix 3.0.2
Using addressable 2.5.2
Using bundler 1.16.6
Using mini_mime 1.0.0
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Fetching nokogiri 1.8.2
Installing nokogiri 1.8.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/Users/kenkuts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2/ext/nokogiri
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r
./siteconf20181215-54662-1izm05e.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine
unf_ext --version 0.0.7.5
Ignoring websocket-driver-0.7.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem
pristine websocket-driver --version 0.7.0
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in
`try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in
`block in try_compile'
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:522:in
`with_werror'
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in
`try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:138:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:162:in `block in add_cflags'
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:629:in
`with_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:161:in `add_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:410:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

/Users/kenkuts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.8.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/kenkuts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/kenkuts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.8.2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  capybara was resolved to 2.18.0, which depends on
    xpath was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      nokogiri
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to download Xcode from the App Store, and run the commands

```
xcode-select --install
sudo xcodebuild -license`
```

The nokogiri install instructions mention this:

https://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#install_with_included_libraries__recommended_

Comment: funny thing is I already have that installed and it still gives me an error.

Comment: @Kenkuts which error does it give you when you gem install nokogiri?

Comment: If you are using Homebrew I've had brew install libiconv and  brew install libyaml help in the past

Comment: @JayDorsey I noticed that I have xcode installed but not gcc. Would it alleviate the issue if I install gcc?

Comment: @Kenkuts yes, you probably also need gcc. there may be some other dependencies as well (libxml2 possibly).

Comment: @JayDorsey I downloaded and installed gcc and when I run xcodebuild it gives me an error.

Comment: Also if you can, link or paste the full mkmf.log file

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an "answer" as much as a set of (hopefully) helpful things too long for a comment.

#### Sandbox your gems

I always run bundler in the following way now, so that one project's dependencies have no impact on the gems I use system wide or on other projects:

```
bundle install --binstubs --path=vendor.noindex
```

That will put all executables in `PROJECT_DIR/bin` and all gems in `PROJECT_DIR/vendor.noindex`. The "noindex" bit stops Spotlight from indexing the gems. To run rspec would now be:

```
bin/rspec
```

To start from a clean slate I run:

```
rm -rf .bundle bin Gemfile.lock vendor.noindex
```

Note: Always be careful using an `rm -rf`!!!!

#### Installing and finding dependencies

The last time I installed Nokogiri using the `gem install` command it looked like this:

```
gem install nokogiri -- \
                     --use-system-libraries \ 
                     --with-xml2-include=/opt/pkg/include/libxml2 \
                     --with-xml2-lib=/opt/pkg/lib \
                     --with-xslt-include=/opt/pkg/include/libxslt \
                     --with-xslt-lib=/opt/pkg/lib
```

As other commenters have noticed, this shows that you need XCode installed (always worth checking for updates) and that I've used libraries installed by another package manager (I've used [pkgrsc](https://pkgsrc.joyent.com/) above though you could use [Macports](http://macports.org/) or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and maybe some others).

To find the libs you need to link to try running:

```
find `/usr` -name libxml2 -type d 2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied' >&2)
```

Or change the `/usr` to `/opt` if you're installing there via pkgsrc/Macports/Fink etc. You may need to put a `sudo` in front depending on the permissions.

There's also the `locate` command, e.g.

```
locate libxml2
```

Which will bring up lots of stuff.